# React-native error requiring unknown module 'react'

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

When I run my react-native app with Xcode, and after the app starts to load, I see this error:

```
"Requiring unknown module "react". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager."
```

My package.json contents are:

```
{
  "name": "the_golf_mentor",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-cookies": "^0.0.5",
    "react-native-db-models": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-navbar": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.18.0",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.3.3"
  }
}
```

I have tried restarting the package manager, and I have also removed the node_module folder and done a fresh `npm install`. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try to install React also, like `npm install --save react`

Comment: @MotiAzu All packages are lower-case only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the error message was an interim one I was receiving in the debugger. When  I pressed continue a couple of times in the debugger, I received a message in the simulator window which indicated I had not registering the app properly, i.e. my `AppRegistry.registerComponent` call was invalid.

I suspect this was an unusual cause of the `unknown module 'react'` error message. In many cases, `neciu's` answer is probably more useful, so I have also upvoted it as well.

Answer (score 8):

I had this after enabling hot reloading, and then downgrading my react version to support a library I was using.

Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Got it running again.

Comment: This worked and I don't know why. How can deleting the app not work but wiping the simulator can, when the problem resides from React. Anyway, this worked.

Answer (score 3):

In React Native `React` lives in `react-native` module instead of `react` (for React JS). In that case import `React` and other React Native modules via:

```
import React, {
    Component,
    View,        
    Text,
    // other React Native modules
} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: This is no longer the case (I think since 0.25)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error. I closed down IDE and restarted, it worked for me. If nothing works out, try `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You should require `React` from `react-native` in a react-native project, and not from `react`.

```
var React = require('react-native');
```

Comment: The React Native tutorial shows otherwise: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content. I believe this was changed with some version of React Native.

Comment: Yes, it did change since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue: "Error: Requiring Unknown module 3" after installing '@react-navigation/native', so I did the following to fix it:

1. Close everything (Metro, Debugger and Simulator)
2. npm install
3. npx pod-install ios (On Mac)
4. npm run ios

and that's it!